# Runtime type checks in Typescript library - worth it?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

Still somewhat new to Typescript (and Type checking) and wondering what the best practices are involved around runtime type checks on things like arguments and props.

I'm currently creating a library of React components and while testing them it occurred to me that because I'm using Typescript, I skipped doing run time checks that I normally would do in vanilla JS. While it's great that TS handles it for TS consumers, regular JS consumers won't get any warnings if they don't provide the right types.

Should I take the lazy route and shun the non-Typescript user, or would it be better to manually add runtime support, plus write the tests for that support? If I do this, it's obviously substantial work and seems like it would partly defeat the purpose of using Typescript...

Related question: is there a way to write a test based on the TS compiler? Non working example assuming Jest:

```js
formatTags(tags: string[]): string {
  return tags.join(', ');
}

it('formatTags() fails with the wrong args', () => {
  let tagList: string = formatTags(); // TS Error (missing param)
  expect(tagList).toThrowTypescriptError('Property `tags` is missing on type...') // pseudo code

  taglist = formatTags(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'something else'); // TS Error (extra param)
  expect(tagList).toThrowTypescriptError('Argument of type `something else` is not assignable...') // psuedo code
}
```

The idea is to have an automated test consuming the API (without runtime checks). Right now I'm basically doing it via a demo app.

Comment: Your question is a little bit opinion based. Also, the way you design your package API and what may happens with the wrong type as an input would change the answer. IMO, about 99% of the cases I won't add a type checking for a `Typescript` package. About the tool, Facebook has released a [tool for static type checking name Flow](https://flow.org/).

Comment: @Old Fox Thanks for your comment. The most common problem I'm referring to is warning the user if they don't provide the right args to the exposed public functions (e.g. React components). If they are developing with TS it's solved, but not if they are using JS. Also, since I'm building a library of React components, I've found it necessary to have a separate app like Storybook to manually test the consumer interface. Of course it's useful for the visual anyway, but if I could automate some of this in a test runner, it seems faster.

Comment: In some ways yes I am asking for opinions, although I'm also specifically asking how to achieve things. But even if I weren't, I'm sorry you feel that way. IMO "best practices" questions have been some of the hands down most valuable type of questions for me on SO. It is a big shame that they are discouraged, but I'm frankly glad ppl ask them anyway and that they show up easily in Google. I've learned a ton from them.

Comment: I'm sad that no real discussion came up in this thread. I've been wondering about this topic for a couple of days now.

Comment: @unleash.it Have you come up with an answer to you question withing those nearly 2 years?

Comment: @MrSegFaulty because it was censored. Sadly this site and by extension our world today doesn't celebrate free thought or critical thinking. "Best practices" posts are some of the best on SO. Luckily, a few the better ones are allowed to live despite the "rulez" if they get lucky and have someone with a high enough score answer.

Comment: @MrSegFaulty I have come across some libraries that can convert some Typescript checks into runtime (I believe through a compile time process), but I've never used them and couldn't recommend you anything in particular. For my use when I'm writing a library (and from what I've seen others do) is to continue to write them manually.

Comment: Oh and you could always use a schema validator like Yup/Joi if you have a lot of user input and want to cut back on some boilerplate.

Comment: @unleash.it Cool. Thanks for the answer. I guess my approach would be: if I have time to make runtime type checks, I will do them.